# I am facing an issue while integerating paystack to wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, payment, elementor, paystack

I have a website in wordpress in which i want to integerate paystack, the site has the ability of memberships. it is a job posting site when the job poster and seeker both pay, so how i will integerate paystack in it. please help me in this regard

I just want someone to help me integerate paystack like stripe or paypal which is already integerate in the site

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Show some effort and focus, please.